# C++11 MSVS vs GCC visibility of template parameter name in static member initialization

Tags: templates, c++11, lambda, compiler-errors, static-members

I just want to ask why MSVS2013 complains with this code unlike GCC(4.8.3 at least):

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    typedef std::function<T*()> FunctionType;
    static FunctionType funcObj;
};

template <typename T> typename MyClass<T>::FunctionType MyClass<T>::funcObj =
    []{return new T();};
```

In msvs2013, it complains this:
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'T'

And to fix, i have to modify it to this:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    typedef std::function<T*()> FunctionType;
    static FunctionType funcObj;

    static T* foo()
    {
        return new T();
    }
};

template <typename T> typename MyClass<T>::FunctionType MyClass<T>::funcObj =
    MyClass<T>::foo;
```

NOTE: 'MyClass < T > ::' is not necessary at the last line. I just want to imply that T is still usable on the right hand side of the operation(to be assigned), and when T was inside the lambda, it is not usable anymore.

Which one complies correctly in the current standard?
Is there any way to ensure that the typename is still usable in a lambda in such cases?

Thank you in advance!

---

**Edit**

The issue seems to be fixed in the current version, such that the first version works in MSVS too.

Comment: Are you talking about C++11 or C++14?

Comment: I am talking about C++11 :)

Comment: I am far from being a language lawyer but as far as I can tell after carefully re-reading your code, I cannot see why this shouldn't be valid C++11.  Anyway, what do you mean with this: *“Is there any way to ensure that the typename is still usable in a lambda in such cases?”*

Comment: This won't help you decide whether it's valid per the standard or not but as a workaround, you can use `static FunctionType getFunctor() { static FunctionType lambda = []{ return new T {}; }; return lambda; }` which I'm pretty sure is valid C++11.  If this is not a toy example, I would of course recommend against making `lambda` `static` here because it doesn't really help anything but might have a performance penalty.

Comment: [Compiles for me](http://rextester.com/CCTXE10629) with MSVC.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, you tried using the first code and used it so that it will be generated with the binary?

like this?:
struct Object {};

auto x = MyClass<Object>::funcObj();

Comment: @NJAldea, you tried clicking on the link?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, ah yes. but I have to use the template class so that it will be instantiated

    struct Object
    {
    };

    int main()
    {
        auto x = MyClass<Object>::funcObj();  
    }

Comment: @5gon12eder, what I understood in MSVS is that 'T' is not accepatable anymore when I used it inside the lambda(only in the case of the example I had given). I can't see why it should not too that is why I am asking here which one is correct. :/

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, [this is what I meant](http://rextester.com/HAO25359).:)
sorry, This is my first time doing this :)

Comment: TIL you can omit empty lambda parameter lists. Other than that, I'd really like to know whether this is valid C++11 too. My guess would be that it is, and the error message is a bug in the Visual C++ compiler; but that's really only a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC is not standard compliant, because the standard says (§9.4.2 [class.static.data]):

> The initializer expression in the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class

Clearly, the template parameter `T` is in the scope of the template class, therefore its name should be available in the initializer of of the static member `funcObj`. Lambdas inherit the types of the enclosing scope, so this version *is* standard compliant:

```
template <typename T> typename MyClass<T>::FunctionType MyClass<T>::funcObj =
[]{return new T();};
```

Comment: Good find -- thanks.  Have an upvote for that :)  Don't forget to file a bug report with the Visual Studio guys!

Comment: @LThode took me a while :-)

Comment: Thanks guys!!! At least I am not the only one in doubt :)

I hope MSVS will be standard compliant with regards to C++... Intellisense is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC is pretty clearly in the wrong here; I checked on [Godbolt](http://goo.gl/ZPPHGb) and Clang, ICC, and GCC all accept your first code once a `#include <functional>` is stuffed in front of it.  You may want to file a bug report on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) as well...

Comment: I would prefer an answer that refers to the standard and not on a quorum of widespread compilers.

Comment: @user1978011 -- I checked several spots in n3797, but haven't found anything talking about lambda syntax.  I suppose I can keep looking though...